# Can I catch VSTS Agent output with SDK?

Tags: build, azure-devops

I'm trying to write simple CLI tool, helping me with several VSTS-related tasks, like:

- Create project from template
- Building and watching build from console
- etc

So, it would be nice to attach to running build (triggered via CI) and watch console output in live in my desktop console. Is there such ability in SDK?

I'm currently using this packages:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any API can achieve this feature as I know. You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).